# If $f'=[f]^2$ and $f(0)=0$, what we can say about $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, riemann-integration

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable and $f(0)=0$ s.t. $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have

$$f'(x)=[f(x)]^2,$$

where $[x]$ is the least integer greater than or equal to $x.$

> Show that $f(x)=0$, for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

I tried to take the Riemann integral of both sides and I got stuck. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Could the Mean Value Theorem help?

Comment: I added the "ordinary-differential-equations" tag to your post.  Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By [Darboux's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)), the derivative of a differentiable function has the intermediate value property.  But the derivative of a solution to your equation $f'(x) = \left[ f(x)\right]^2$ only takes integer values.  Therefore solutions to this equation must be constant.

Comment: Short and sweet!